Difference scheme for time-reversed heat conduction equation
I am working on solving the time-reversed heat conduction equation(assuming a two-dimensional space with Dirichlet boundary conditions). I have implemented the finite difference method, using first-order implicit time advancing and second-order central scheme, which forms that
$$
T_{i,j}^{n+1} = T_{i,j}^n + \Delta t \alpha \left( \frac{T_{i-1,j}^{n+1} - 2T_{i,j}^{n+1} + T_{i+1,1}^{n+1}}{\Delta x^2}+\frac{T_{i,j-1}^{n+1} - 2T_{i,j}^{n+1} + T_{i,j+1}^{n+1}}{\Delta y^2}\right)
$$
However, I've encountered an issue where the solution tends to diverge when solving the inversion problem with negative time steps. Could anyone suggest a more reliable difference scheme that can handle this situation? Additionally, are there any researchers or papers that have addressed similar issues? Thank you for your help!
